# Program crashed after entering 10 strings

Tags: c++, string, list

This program is supposed to read 10 strings from the keyboard together with 5 other words which forms a list of strings. It will randomly pick one word in the list and replace all the vowels. Then the program will ask you to guess. However, the program crashed after I enter 10 strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

int randomnum(){
int g, r, f = 0;
/*init random number generator*/
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));/*get a random num*/
g = rand();
r = (g % 13) + 1;
return(r);
}

int main(){
int k,l,f;
std::string *str = new std::string[14];
str[0] = "computer";
str[1] = "television";
str[2] = "keyboard";
str[3] = "magazine";
str[4] = "book";

std::cout<< "please enter 10 strings" <<std::endl;/*get strings into the array*/
    for(int i = 5;i < 15; i++){
            std::cin>>str[i];
    }
k = randomnum();
std::string e = str[k];
l= e.size();

char letter[l - 1];
strcpy(letter,e.c_str());

for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if(letter[i] == 'a' || letter[i] =='e' || letter[i] == 'i' || letter[i] == 'o' || letter[i] == 'u' || letter[i] == 'A'|| letter[i] == 'E' || letter[i] =='I'
            || letter[i] == 'O'||letter[i] == 'U'){/*replace the vowel*/
            letter[i] = '_';
        }

    }
std::cout<< "Please guess the word: " << letter <<std::endl;
std::string gue;
std::cin>> gue;
if(gue == e) {
f++;
std::cin.clear();
std::cout<<"You guessed correct after "<< f << "guesses, Do you want to play it again?"<< std::endl;/*check the number and return the result*/
}
if(gue == "zzz"){
    exit(0);
}
else{
    f++;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout<<" Incorrect, guess another one!"<< std::endl;
    std::cin>>gue;
}
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.sync();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string *str = new std::string[14];
```

should be

```
std::string *str = new std::string[15];
```

otherwise you will only be able to add 9 more strings to the array

Answer (score 1):

It's because you allocate space for 14 strings, but write *15* strings. My advice is to not use pointers, but [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).